# Validating specific column in grep

Tags: regex, sed, grep

Ok this is driving me crazy. I have a text file with the following content:

```
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-01-01","2020-12-13","4"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-07","2020-12-03","22"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-12","2020-04-11","21"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-05-21","2020-03-23","453"
```

etc.

I want to filter lines on which the **second date** is in december, I tried things like:

```
grep '.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*(2020-12-).*' > output.txt
grep '.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*2020-12-.*' > output.txt
grep -P '.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*2020-12-.*' > output.txt
```

But nothing seems to work. Is there any way to accomplish this with either grep, egrep, sed or awk?

Comment: See: [Filtering lines in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65416773/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-P` option of `grep` to enable perl compatible regular expressions, could you please try following. Written and tested with your shown samples.

```
grep -P '("\d+",){4}"[a-zA-Z]+","2020-12-\d{2}"' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above, following is only for explanation purposes.

```
grep             ##Starting grep command from here.
-P               ##Mentioning -P option for enabling PCRE regex with grep.
'("\d+",){4}     ##Looking for " digits " comma this combination 4 times here.
"[a-zA-Z]+",     ##Then looking for " alphabets ", with this one.
"2020-12-\d{2}"  ##Then looking for " 2020-12-07 date " which OP needs.
' Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Or in case you want to simply look for date `2020-12-07` in 6th field in your file then we could simply do `awk -F'","' '$6=="2020-12-12"' Input_file` for this one too.

Comment: Note that OP wants any date in December. I agree, though, that `awk` is probably better as there are distinct columns here.

Comment: @KenY-N, sure, thank you for letting know, I have changed the regex now, to catch any date in December month.

Comment: I tried it with a small modification, as:

grep -P '.*"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}","2020-12-\d{2}"' in.csv > december_2020.csv

To ignore the first date column ... and it works! I guess the -P did the charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest an alternate solution `awk` due to input data structured in rows and columns using a common delimiter:

```sh
awk -F, '$7 ~ /-12-/' file

"1","2","3","4","text","2020-01-01","2020-12-13","4"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-07","2020-12-03","22"
```

Comment: Yep, tried this too, it also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `grep -P` or `egrep` for short:

```
$ cat test.txt
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-01-01","2020-12-13","4"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-07","2020-12-03","22"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-12","2020-04-11","21"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-05-21","2020-03-23","453"
$
$ grep -P '^"([^"]*","){6}2020-12-' test.txt
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-01-01","2020-12-13","4"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-07","2020-12-03","22"
$
$ egrep '^"([^"]*","){6}2020-12-' test.txt
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-01-01","2020-12-13","4"
"1","2","3","4","text","2020-12-07","2020-12-03","22"
```

Explanation:

- `^"` - expect a `"` to start
- `([^"]*","){6}` - scan over all chars other than `"`, followed by `","`; repeat that 6 times
- `2020-12-` - expect `202012-`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in:

```
egrep '.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.2020-12-.' > output.txt
                          ^ HERE
```

The `.` just matches a single character, but you want to skip `","`, so change to:

```
egrep '.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.+2020-12-.' > output.txt
                          ^^ HERE
```

The `.` becomes a `.+`.

Comment: That's by no means the only problem here. `grep` typically does not support `\d` at all, and you are looking for a match in any column.